# Easiest way to install Hadoop in a VM on Windows 7?

Tags: hadoop, centos, virtual-machine

I am reading a book about Hadoop now.  The books says you need to download and install VMware Workstation Player (Windows 7 version)

https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/14_0

Then, apparently, I need to download and install CentOS6, from here.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/centos-6-vmware/

Once the VM is running, you need to go to File > Open, and run the centos program.  The problem I am having is that I can't install the VM; I'm getting an error message that reads 'This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled'.  So, I Googled this, and I don't have anything that is listed there (no Processor submenu, no Chipset, Advanced CPU Configuration, and no Northbridge).  There must install Hadoop, I hope.  What is the easiest way to get this up and running on a Windows 7 machine?  I just want to follow some of the steps from the book.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I got in installed.  Hit F1 to get to the BIOS, and then look for 'Virtualization' and select Intel Virtual Tech = Enabled.

Comment: Answer your own question and close it.

Comment: First, Hadoop will run fine on windows. But please don't use Centos 6. Use 7. And Hortonworks or Cloudera offer pre-installed Hadoop VMs